# Использование Async/await для обработки URL

Tags: javascript, url, async-await, promise

У меня есть следующая задача.

Задача 2
Написать функцию, принимающую список url путей и возвращающую промис, который резолвит результаты всех запросов по указанным url (важно: резолвит массив значений, резолвит не раньше последнего из запросов, не использовать Promise.all)
P.S. список url - так как функция запроса фейковая, то под списком url стоить понимать любой массив строк.

ФУНКЦИЯ ЗАПРОСА:

```
function request(url) {
return new Promise((res, rej) => {
const delayTime = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000) + 1;

setTimeout(() => res(url), delayTime);
});
}
```

Возникли две проблемы:

- первая если попробовать через Promise.all, тогда получаю undefined: undefined;
- вторая если писать через асинк/аваит, не могу сделать аналог new promise в котором будет ресолве -> forEach перебрать массив -> пушнуть в arr -> резолв.

Моя попытка.

```js
const URL = [
  'https://www.google.com.ua/',
  'https://www.bing.com/',
  'https://www.yahoo.com/'
];

const RESPONSE = [];

function request(URL) {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    const delayTime = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000) + 1;
    setTimeout(() => res(URL), delayTime);
  });
}

let requests = URL.map(URL => request(URL));

async function urlResponses() {
  let requests = await URL.map(forEach(URL => request(URL)));
  return RESPONSE.push(result)
}

// Promise.all(requests)
//   .then(responses => responses.forEach(
//     response => alert(`${response.url}: ${response.status}`)
//   ));
```

Comment: _первая если попробовать через Promise.all, тогда получаю undefined: undefined;_ - ты получаешь `undefined`, потому что у тебя в массиве строки лежат, а не объекты с полями `url` и `status`, а строки у тебя там лежат, потому что ты делаешь не настоящий запрос

Comment: Посмотрите в [эту сторону](https://quentin.pradet.me/blog/you-dont-need-promises-in-python-just-use-asyncawait.html)

Comment: @Serg Bocharov, в "этой стороне" автору удобней await-ить; ну, иногда удобней, инигда нет; реализация всё равно на промисах

Answer (score 0):

```js
const URL = [ 
'https://www.google.com.ua/',
'https://www.bing.com/',
'https://www.yahoo.com/'
];

function request(URL) {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        const delayTime = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000) + 1;
        setTimeout(() => res(URL+" -- "+delayTime), delayTime);
    });
}

async function urlResponses () {
  const promises = URL.map(u => request(u))
  const response = []
  for(promise of promises) response.push(await promise)
  return response
}

urlResponses().then(r=>console.log(r))
```

Comment: если Promise.all вам разрешен, то просто `return Promise.all(URL.map(u => request(u)))`